# install opencv into a virtual environment

Tags: python, installation, virtualenv

I need to use opencv in a project that is in a virtual environment, but you cannot install opencv with pip.

installing on my local machine (OSX Yosemite, version 10.10.1) with homebrew works just fine, but I cannot do "brew install" in my virtualenv.

How can I include opencv in my environment?

Comment: Do you want to install OpenCV only in virtualenv or just make OpenCV work in virtualenv?

Comment: Ideally I would want it in the virtualenv so that others can copy my identical environment.

Comment: I've been looking around on the web and I found this [blog post](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/15/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-osx/). Hope it helps!

Answer (score 5):

As described [here](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/09/19/pip-install-opencv/) (see Option B) you can run this from inside your virtual environment:

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

As mentioned at that link, `opencv-contrib-python` is an *unofficial* pre-built OpenCV package.

I tested this on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

I use Windows 10. In my case, in order to use openCV in my new virtual environment, I manually copied **all of the files regarding openCV** which are in C:\Program Files (x86)\python36\Lib\site-packages to **virtual environment directory** C:\Program Files (x86)\ibrahim\Lib\site-packages. Then, **import cv2** to python and it worked for me. Be noted that you need to **copy all of the files inside red boxes** that I showed below.

[image: **Files inside red boxes to be deleted**]

Answer (score 0):

For OpenCV 2, [try this.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19213369/1510289)

Basically, install Python bindings for OpenCV 2 system-wide, then copy the library file into your virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

To make OpenCV available within the virtual environment, if this installed as a "system-wide package", extend the Python-path with the location where the package is installed. E.g. (on Ubuntu, after installation of prebuild package python3-opencv)

```
import sys
sys.path.extend([
    "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages"
])

import cv2 as cv
print("OpenCV version:", cv.__version__)
```